# React Native Not Running projects that I copied from Windows machine to Ubuntu

Tags: react-native

I just moved to Ubuntu from Windows 10, I have installed react-native on my laptop and everytime I do **react-native init** it creates a project as expected. **react-native run-android & react-native start** commands are working as you'd expect them to be.

My main problem is I just copied a react native project from my Windows 10 machine to Ubuntu and now everytime I do **react-native run-android** This is the error I see on my console

**This is the error I see on my console**

> Starting JS server... 
>   Running /home/adeel/Android/Sdk//platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug... 
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the React Native project was created in Windows and I was trying to run it in a Linux based platform. So what I did was I created a brand new project in my Linux environment and copied my RN code in the newly created project.
This was I believe due to the android file it created which is platform dependent. Windows and Linux have different GRADLE files. I hope this helps anyone who is having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is not recognizing your device/emulator. Run "adb devices" to check. I guess you did the whole Android setup and installed Android Studio (SDK).

Comment: Hi @RN_starter I did use adb devices and it shows the current emulator/devices connected. What i did was created a new project with 'react-native init <project name>' and just copied all the old files from the project to the new project created. 
I guess the problem is gradle built for Windows and Linux are different (not sure). But anyways I fixed the problem.